# create shortcut in cmd prompt using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am using python and virutal environment in windows7. Every time I need to go to the project folder, shift+right click to open command prompt and activate virtualenv.
Instead I can hit win+R them type cmd to open a command prompt.

Then type

```
C:\cd D:\path\to\project
D:
workon projectEnvironment
```

Can this be done to create a shortchut like 'work' from autohotkey ??

Comment: @MCL, ya sure, but how can this be done...

Comment: Use the `Send` command.

Answer (score 1):

Your windows-R shortcut would work like this:
Start a cmd window and wait until it is active.

Then begin to send your commands.

```
#r::
Run, %comspec% /c cmd.exe
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinWaitActive, cmd.exe
SendInput, cd D:\projects\folder{enter} 
SendInput, D:{enter} 
SendInput, workon projectEnvironment{enter}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I was unable to create shortcut key combination in cmd, I created a shortcut key, i.e. windows button + space

```
#space::Send cd D:\projects\folder{enter} D:{enter} workon projectEnvironment {enter}
```

## Edit

here's the real solution

```
::work::cd D:\projects\folder{enter} D:{enter} workon projectEnvironment {enter}
```

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of researching why my script would write `"` instead of `\` when Sending a path in cmd prompt, I realized that sometimes the cmd prompt will interpret some keys differently for AutoHotkey.

I used to write `Send, cd C:\File\Path {Enter}` and it returned:

```
C:"File"Path
```

You can use [ASC codes](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/slash-forward-slash-fraction-bar-division-ascii-code-47.html) for `/` = `{ASC 47}` and `\` = `{ASC 92}`, which in the end you write:

```
Send, cd C:{ASC 92}File{ASC 92}Path {Enter}
```